# Creating an arc between two points for interpolation in Java

Tags: java, interpolation, spline

I've got a top down game that I'm making and I want my enemies to be able to move across the screen in an arc. Right now they move in a straight line between two edges of the screen. I generate a start position on one edge then find a random position somewhere across the screen and calculate movement speeds my multiplying the sin/cos of the angle by their speed variable.

I'd like to use these  to points to generate some arc between them and then use that to move my enemies along it. I thought maybe some sort of spline would do the trick but Im not entirely sure how to create one, nor more significantly how to use it to interpolate my characters. I think at this point its more of a math question than programming but I hope someone can help anyways. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a spline would work for you.  Specifically i would recommend a cubic spline, because later on if you wanted do a different shape, maybe a Street Fighter style uppercut, you could re-use the same code.  I remember cubic spline being a decent, general solution.

As far as solving for a cubic spline I would recommend you just Google for pseudo code which makes sense to you.  That's only if you really want to generically solve for a suitable cubic spline on the fly.

In practice, i imagine the shape you want will be the same almost all the time?  If so, you can probably solve a few general cases of a spline and save it to some fast data structure to improve performance. In example, for `y=x` a suitable array holding the necessary information (pre-processed) would be `x[0] = 1,x[1] = 1,x[2] = 2 ... x[n] = n`.

In practice, you could come up with an equation to model a simple two point spline.  A cubic equation has 4 unknowns.  So you have two data points at least, you're starting point and your end point.  In addition, you can calculate the derivative of him when he jumps.  For your fourth point you could use either another point you want him to jump through, or the derivative when he lands.  Then use https://www.wolframalpha.com/ to solve the equation for you.  Or use an equation to solve cubics.

Another thing you can do is just calculate the arc using the quadratic equation + gravity + wind resistance.  Again, Google knows how to solve that.  This page is something i quickly found that looks like it could do the trick.  http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/Lesson-2/Non-Horizontally-Launched-Projectiles-Problem-Solv

Answer (score 0):

When you intend to use a spline, you can use the `Path2D` class that is already available in Java. You can assemble an arbitrary path by

- moving to a certain point
- appending a line segment
- appending a quadratic curve segment
- appending a cubic curve segment

So assembling this path should be easy: You can just create a quadratic curve that starts at a random point on the left border of the screen and ends at a random point on the right border of the screen. As the control points (for both ends) you can use a point at a random position in the center of the screen.

(BTW: When you manage to represent the path as a generic `Path2D`, then you can probably imagine that you have quite a lot of freedom when designing the path for the enemies. They could run in circles or zig-zag, just as you like...)

What might be more tricky here is to let the enemies *follow* this path.

The first step is not sooo tricky yet: You can walk along this path with a `PathIterator`. But this `PathIterator` will only return a single segment - namely, the quadratic curve. This can be alleviated by creating a *flattening* `PathIterator`. This will convert all curves into line segments (the resolution can be high, so you won't notice any corners).

However, now comes the really tricky part: When iterating these line segments, the movement speed may vary: Depending on the curvature of the original quadratic curve, there may be more or fewer line segments be created. In the worst case, when all 3 points are on one line, then only *one* line segment would be created, and the enemy would walk across the whole screen in a single step. So you have to make sure that this path is traversed with a constant speed. You have to compute how far you already have been walking when iterating over the path, and possibly interpolate a position between two points of the path.

I quickly assembled an example. It's certainly not bullet-proof, but might serve as a starting point.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class SplineMovementTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static PathFollower pathFollower;

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        final Random random = new Random(0);

        final SplineMovementPanel p = new SplineMovementPanel();

        JButton generateButton = new JButton("Generate");
        generateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Shape spline = generateSpline(p,
                    random.nextDouble(),  
                    random.nextDouble(),  
                    random.nextDouble());
                p.setSpline(spline);
                pathFollower = new PathFollower(spline);
                p.repaint();
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(generateButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        startAnimation(p);

        frame.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static Shape generateSpline(
        JComponent c, double yLeft, double yCenter, double yRight)
    {
        Path2D spline = new Path2D.Double();
        double x0 = 0;
        double y0 = yLeft * c.getHeight();
        double x1 = c.getWidth() / 2;
        double y1 = yCenter * c.getHeight();
        double x2 = c.getWidth();
        double y2 = yRight * c.getHeight();
        spline.moveTo(x0, y0);
        spline.curveTo(x1, y1, x1, y1, x2, y2);
        return spline;
    }

    private static void startAnimation(final SplineMovementPanel p)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener()
        {
            double position = 0.0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                position += 0.005;
                position %= 1.0;
                if (pathFollower != null)
                {
                    Point2D point = pathFollower.computePointAt(
                        position * pathFollower.getPathLength());
                    p.setObjectLocation(point);
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
}

class PathFollower
{
    private final List<Point2D> points;
    private final double pathLength;

    PathFollower(Shape spline)
    {
        points = createPointList(spline);
        pathLength = computeLength(points);
    }

    public double getPathLength()
    {
        return pathLength;
    }

    Point2D computePointAt(double length)
    {
        if (length < 0)
        {
            Point2D p = points.get(0);
            return new Point2D.Double(p.getX(), p.getY());
        }
        if (length > pathLength)
        {
            Point2D p = points.get(points.size()-1);
            return new Point2D.Double(p.getX(), p.getY());
        }
        double currentLength = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<points.size()-1; i++)
        {
            Point2D p0 = points.get(i);
            Point2D p1 = points.get(i+1);
            double distance = p0.distance(p1);
            double nextLength = currentLength + distance;
            if (nextLength > length)
            {
                double rel = 1 - (nextLength - length) / distance;
                double x0 = p0.getX();
                double y0 = p0.getY();
                double dx = p1.getX() - p0.getX();
                double dy = p1.getY() - p0.getY();
                double x = x0 + rel * dx;
                double y = y0 + rel * dy;
                return new Point2D.Double(x,y);
            }
            currentLength = nextLength;
        }
        Point2D p = points.get(points.size()-1);
        return new Point2D.Double(p.getX(), p.getY());
    }

    private static double computeLength(List<Point2D> points)
    {
        double length = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<points.size()-1; i++)
        {
            Point2D p0 = points.get(i);
            Point2D p1 = points.get(i+1);
            length += p0.distance(p1);
        }
        return length;
    }

    private static List<Point2D> createPointList(Shape shape)
    {
        List<Point2D> points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
        PathIterator pi = shape.getPathIterator(null,  0.1);
        double coords[] = new double[6];
        while (!pi.isDone())
        {
            int s = pi.currentSegment(coords);
            switch (s)
            {
                case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                    points.add(new Point2D.Double(coords[0], coords[1]));

                case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                    points.add(new Point2D.Double(coords[0], coords[1]));
            }
            pi.next();
        }
        return points;
    }

}


class SplineMovementPanel extends JPanel
{
    void setSpline(Shape shape)
    {
        this.spline = shape;
    }

    void setObjectLocation(Point2D objectLocation)
    {
        this.objectLocation = objectLocation;
        repaint();
    }
    private Shape spline = null;
    private Point2D objectLocation = null;


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        if (spline != null)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.draw(spline);
        }

        if (objectLocation != null)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            int x = (int)objectLocation.getX()-15;
            int y = (int)objectLocation.getY()-15;
            g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
        }
    }


}
```